# Upload files to another domain - Incorrect property files to destination

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

Using a form + PHP upload files in a folder 
This works fine.

Those same files, I have to replicate in another domain.
The upload is via FTP with this piece of code:

```
 define("FTP_ADDRESS","DESTINY_SERVER");
 define("FTP_USERNAME","MY_FTP_USER");
 define("FTP_PASSWORD","PASSWORD_FTP");

 $LOCAL_FILE = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0];
 $FTP_FILE = "LA_RUTA_DE_DESTINO";

 $conn = ftp_connect(FTP_ADDRESS);
 $login = ftp_login($conn, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
 ftp_put($conn, $FTP_FILE, $LOCAL_FILE, FTP_ASCII);
 ftp_close($conn);
```

This uploading files to another domain works PERFECTLY.

The problem is that in another domain, the target domain, if I run a modification on the files uploaded gives me permission issues.

Uploads files via POST forms has as property the APACHE user.
But these, uploaded through FTP with PHP function, MY_FTP_USER have as owner, so then I can do nothing with them using PHP and should be able to manipulate them using a php CMS

What can I do to make the files are uploaded to a FTP, and then from PHP can manipulate them without problem?

There are issues of CHMOD permissions are user property issues.

Comment: Could you post the error please?

Comment: The upload vía PHP FTP is ok
If modified the file on DESTINY server, have permission error: "Permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

You can change file permission level of file after file upload after upload. Put your php user in same group with APACHE user and;

```
$conn = ftp_connect(FTP_ADDRESS);
 $login = ftp_login($conn, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
 ftp_put($conn, $FTP_FILE, $LOCAL_FILE, FTP_ASCII);

 // Change permission
 if (ftp_chmod($conn, 0664, $FTP_FILE) !== false) {
    echo "$file chmoded successfully to 0664\n";
 } else {
    echo "Could not chmod $file\n";
 }
 ftp_close($conn);
```

**664** => group users can modify files

Comment: I use ftp_chmod function, setting 0664
If modified file on destiny server, i have this error:

copy(../images/noticias/118_0_orig.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: See my updated answer, and you need to chmod file after ftp_put

Comment: Yeah, I know, modifying permissions have to go after the file uploading.


I have it as well

`define("FTP_ADDRESS","DESTINY_SERVER");
define("FTP_USERNAME","MY_FTP_USER");
define("FTP_PASSWORD","PASSWORD_FTP");
$LOCAL_FILE = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0];
$FTP_FILE = "LA_RUTA_DE_DESTINO";
$conn = ftp_connect(FTP_ADDRESS);
$login = ftp_login($conn, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
ftp_put($conn, $FTP_FILE, $LOCAL_FILE, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_chmod($conn, 0777, $FTP_FILE);
ftp_close($conn);`